# Can client in some way affect work of my Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, security

I mean, there are some developer/other tools that let change variables in Javascript enviroment and so on. Consider I have an AJAX request. So could user, for instance, manipulate variables I send with AJAX request so that they see something they are not used to see? Or, for instance, manipulate value of `<select>` so that it is other, not like in options given. I hope you understand what I mean.

But how to implement AJAX in this case? Can client create his own request? So just send error back if request was not like it should be?

Comment: Added second `<p>` for you new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I send with AJAX request so that they see something they are not used to see?

**YES!**

You can't rely on client side scripting for security!

Check out:

- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

---

**After your edit:**

> Can client create his own request?

Yes.

> So just send error back if request was not like it should be?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "your" Javascript code. It's a bunch of characters you send to the client in the hopes that it will do something useful with it.

Javascript doesn't "work" by default. Everything that happens happens because the client did it. So yes, the client affects *everything* about the workings of your Javascript code.